# how can i trap the logout time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i maintain the Login and Logout time in Asp.net ?

I have store Login and Logout time in the Database..
once user is logged in, we will capture the login time..... but the question is logout time ?

And i have tried to use Session_End Event in global.asa file... its file

In some situation 
1) system shut down automatically
2) user close the browser

in this situation how can i capture the logout time ?

For example (Facebook,Gmail) how they will maintain the user weather the user are in offline r online ?

Same like that i was implementing chatting application, can u guide means to achieve this solution

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the person clicks on `LOGOUT` button manually you can get the logout time. Now, if the person doesn't click the logout button. There is the problem and mostly there is a chance of people not clicking on the `logout` button  and just close the browser. What you can do is

- Add a `Javascript/jQuery` to call a `webmethod` for logout when the browser is closed
- The method should capture the time and logout the user from the session

You will get the browser close warning `javascripts/jQuery` in which you can call a `Webmethod`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: some browser is supporting the browse closed event, some of the browser is not supporting, how can i handle in this situation ?

Comment: I believe almost all the browsers supports it. Just check whether Javascript is blocked in the browser. Hope you are developing a chat window, So, Javascripts are disabled even the chat should not work properly.